# How to check a property or variable is empty and set a value then test for that value

Tags: ant

We are using Ant 1.8. I am not an Ant developer but I have to pretend sometimes.

A new property, ${noReportDSUpgrade}, is intended to be "true" or "false".

By default it is empty (not exist?) which is "false" for our purposes.

If this property is empty it should be set to "false".

A command line using this parameter should set it to true.

1) How do I set ${noReportDSUpgrade} to false if empty and true if supplied?

2) For the target, how to execute only if false?

I have tried several suggestions I've found but can't get it to work.

At the beginning of the script:

```
<target name="init">
    <antcall target="setnoReportDSUpgradeProperty"/>
```

Further down:

```
<target name="setnoReportDSUpgradeProperty">
    <condition>
        <or>
            <equals arg1="${noReportDSUpgrade}" arg2=""/>
            <not>
                <isset property="false"/>
            </not>
       </or>
    </condition>
    <echo message="noReportDSUpgrade set to ${noReportDSUpgrade}"/>         
</target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to set a default property value in Ant:

```
<property name="noReportDSUpgrade" value="false" />
```

That's it! Properties are immutable in Ant, so if you set a value via command line or earlier in the script, subsequent `<property>` tasks won't change it. This won't account for the property being set to a blank value (i.e. ""), but as a general good practice, try to avoid setting properties to blank.

Even though I don't think you need a `<condition>` task for your goals here, I feel I should clear some things up in your example. The `<condition>` task doesn't affect the `<target>` that it's nested in; it simply sets a property, specified by the `property` attribute. Additionally, the `isset` condition's `property` attribute is used to point to the *name* of the property you're checking, not the value.

```
<condition property="noReportDSUpgrade">
    <or>
        <equals arg1="${noReportDSUpgrade}" arg2=""/>
        <not>
            <isset property="noReportDSUpgrade" />
        </not>
    </or>
</condition>
```

But like I said above, don't use that unless you really need to check for a blank value for some reason. Just use `<property>`.

As for running targets conditionally, the `<target>` block supports `if` and `unless` attributes that control whether or not the entire thing runs. This can be a bit confusing because there are two modes in which this operates.

```
<target name="myTarget" if="myCondition">
    <echo message="Running myTarget" />
</target>
```

The above target will run if `myCondition` *is set* (not if its value is true). So if it evaluates to "true", "false", "asdf", or just blank, the target will still run. Conversely, if we used the `unless` attribute, it wouldn't run if `myCondition` is set to anything. This is usually convenient for when you're using the `<condition>` task to set your properties (since `<condition>` does not set a value if the boolean evaluates to false).

```
<target name="myTarget" if="${myCondition}">
    <echo message="Running myTarget" />
</target>
```

Notice the `${}` around myCondition. When you expand the property like this, Ant will only run the target if the property's value is "true", "on", or "yes".

Lastly, you typically don't need to make a separate target just for setting conditions. In relatively simple scripts, you can just use the implicite root target (i.e. put the tasks at root level outside of all other targets).

In short, here's the simplest way to write your script.

```
<project name="myProject">
    <property name="noReportDSUpgrade" value="false" />

    <target name="myTarget" if="${noReportDSUpgrade}">
        <echo message="Running myTarget" />
    </target>
</project>
```

If you really need an initialization target (note the `depends` attribute):

```
<project name="myProject">
    <target name="init">
        <property name="noReportDSUpgrade" value="false" />
    </target>

    <target name="myTarget" if="${noReportDSUpgrade}" depends="init">
        <echo message="Running myTarget" />
    </target>
</project>
```